# How do I create an object nested in a new array using values from an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I currently have an array of string values:
`const array1 = ['string1', 'string2'];`

I want to be able to use the strings from this array and create a new array with nested objects that use them as the values for the object keys. Like this:

`const array2 = [{value: 'string1', label: 'string1'}, {value: 'string2', label: 'string2' ]`;

I've tried using the `.reduce()` method and currently, my code looks like this:

```
const arr = ['string1', 'string2'];
const newArr = [];

function reducer(acc, cur) {
  return {...acc, [cur.id]: cur};
}

const reducedArr = arr.reduce(reducer, {});
newArray.push(reducedArr);
```

When I log `newArray` to the console I'm getting back:

```
Array [{ undefined: 'string2'}]
```

What is the best way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Each element in array2 is a **map**ping of each element of array1.

```js
const array1 = ['string1', 'string2'];
const array2 = array1.map(item => ({value: item, label: item}));
console.log(array2);
```

Comment: Thank you! I realized right after I posted that I should be mapping over it.